# hbase table added index using phoenix but it is taking same time before adding index. Do I need to do something else?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I have created one `hbase` table using phoenix and added data using phoenix bulk upload and also created index table and added reference into index table as well but when I execute and SQL then it will take some time as before adding index table. I have added total 1 millions records in that and find data whose status = 1 but it will take same time as I have added index on status column. Please check screen shot as well.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if I did something wrong and let me know if I need to set some more configration on hbase. let me know your concerns if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Type explain 'your sql query' it should tell you what's going on with your query plan.  Once you have that you can use the index hints with your query and see if that makes any difference. it's best to use the sqlline.py commandline tool

Comment: My query is like this "select * from mobile_phone where status = 0 and caller = '23452342'".